# Editing current data in a data table

Tags: vb.net

I am using following data to add new data to my table

```
Me.TblResultTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DbResultDataSet.tblResult)

Dim drNewRowEditSummary As DataRow
drNewRowEditSummary = DbResultDataSet.tblResult.NewRow
drNewRowEditSummary.Item(1) = "Test"
DbResultDataSet.tblResult.Rows.Add(drNewRowEditSummary)
TblResultTableAdapter.Update(DbResultDataSet.tblResult)
```

How can I edit my data using similar method as above?
Thanks
Furqan

Comment: looks like this might need some quick cleanup re: "enter code here"

Answer (score 0):

DataRowCollection has a [Find-Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydd48eyk%28VS.80%29.aspx) that returns the DataRow with the given primary key(s). So you should define a pk column, then you get the row with:

```
Dim drResult As DataRow = DbResultDataSet.tblResult.Rows.Find(1) 'if your pk is 1'
drResult.Item(1) = "Test2"
TblResultTableAdapter.Update(DbResultDataSet.tblResult)
```

Btw, the same way if you want to delete this row: `drResult.Delete()`

Comment: Not working ! When I run there is no error but my database data is unchanged.  PK is 1

Comment: Also, do not want to use primary key, I donot know what that would be.  I just want to edit it by row no.

Comment: A row has no rownumber. If you define a primary key, you will find the row very fast. What you can do when performance is no issue, use the DataTable.Select function, that returns rows that match your criterias(similar to the where condition in sql): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx You can also simply iterate the RowCollection(DataTable.Rows) and change the values